# Prove that $\forall$A$\forall$B($\forall$C(AUC = BUC) -> (A = B))

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I thought I could say $\forall$C $(A\cup C = B\cup C)$ is False and therefore the whole statement is True.
But I'm not sure whether I understood the whole statement correctly.
Did I get it correctly?

Comment: Given whatever sets you like $A,B$, it if happens to be the case that regardless what third set you take that the unions $A\cup C$ and $B\cup C$ happen to be equal, then that implies that $A=B$.

Comment: As for proving this quickly and easily, consider what happens when you consider that $\emptyset$ is one of the possibilities for $C$.

Comment: Doesn't `∀C(AUC = BUC)` mean that it has to be true for all c? And therefore this is false because it can't be true for all c?

Comment: Let me add a few more parentheses to make it easier to read...  $\forall A\forall B((\forall C(A\cup C=B\cup C))\implies (A=B))$.  Trying to reword it again... for all choices of sets $A$ and $B$, the following implication is true... that if it happens to be the case that $A\cup C=B\cup C$ for all $C$, then that would imply that $A=B$.

Comment: If $C=A$ then $A=A\cup A=B\cup A$ So $B\subseteq A$. If C=B then $A\cup B=B\cup B=B$ So $A\subseteq B$. So $A=B$. So the whole statement is true

Comment: It absolutely can be the case that $A\cup C = B\cup C$ is true for all $C$, and that is precisely what happens in the event that $A=B$

Comment: @JMoravitz If I got you right, what I claimed is wrong?

Comment: Your claim that the hypothesis $\forall C(A\cup C=B\cup C)$ is never true is indeed wrong.  Perhaps you are under the mistaken impression that $A,B,C$ must all be distinct.  That is not the case.  If we wanted $A$ and $B$ to be distinct, we would have said $(\forall A,\forall B\text{such that} A\neq B)$ or something along those lines.  It should be obvious that $A\cup C=A\cup C$ is true for all $C$.  It should be equally obvious that in the event that $A=B$ that $A\cup C=B\cup C$ is true for all $C$.

Comment: @JMoravitz So can I split my proof to two cases? Case 1: A=B and then it will be True -> True, and case 2: A!=B when ∀(∪=∪) = False and therefore False -> True/False is True ?

Comment: There is no need to.  Look at my second comment again... Suppose that $\forall C$ you have that $A\cup C=B\cup C$.  That means it is true when $C=\{1,2,3\}$, that means it is true when $C=\Bbb R$, as well as all of the other infinitely many choices for $C$, and most importantly in particular it is true for when $C=\emptyset$.. so it is true that $A\cup \emptyset = B\cup \emptyset$.  Can you conclude then that $A=B$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, I do understand what you're saying. I'm not sure how to write it formally though.
I've tried to say that Let x$\in$A$\cup$C then x$\in$A$\cap$x$\cup$C, and also x$\in$B$\cup$C then x$\in$B$\cap$x$\cup$C, but now I'm stuck

Comment: My most recent comment *is* a way of proving it formally. You state the hypotheses.  You state that it should work for C equal to the empty set, and you conclude that the implication is true for all hypotheses.